# Bittorrent clients don't remember my "save-to" or "move-completed-torrents-to" locations

Tags: bittorrent, transmission, deluge, torrent-client

I'm using Transmission BitTorrent client and whenever I start the computer it forgets the location where I told it to save my completed downloads as well as incomplete download location! I have to manually assign the location every time I start my computer. Any reason why? How to solve it? I'm using 14.04lts.

I would like to add that the Transmission is started during boot but it doesn't remember locations and says no data found etc. And then I have to manually set the path again and again every time I boot! Please Help!

**Edit:**
Since there were no helpful answers or support or suggestions from the forum, I started hunting the problem on my own and here's what I’ve done; I tried Deluge Bit-torrent client to see if the problem still persists! And it does! **Even deluge doesn’t remember any given saving locations of the files!** So I conclude that the system itself is not able to retain the given location paths and doesn't remember them after a reboot or start-up!
 Another thing I noticed that sometimes; like rarely ever(twice or thrice in past two months) the Transmission client retained one of the "Download-to" or "Move-completed-torrents-to" location(either of two/one of those location) even after start-up/reboot. I never did anything special at that time that it behaves in such a way..

Please help or suggest any trial-and-error methods to reach a solution. Giving locations on every start-up has become a pain! Please help. I’m using 14.04 LTS. 

One more thing I would like to add is that both the "download-in" location and "move-completed-files-to" location are in different drives. Their current name is like this
"download-in" drive name : **EE644C24644BEDC1**
"move-completed-files-to" drive name : **New Volume**.
 Is it because the location is of two different drives?

Comment: Check the transmission config file and see if the permissions are set correctly. (probably `~/.transmission/gtk`)

Comment: where's the config file located? @Rinzwind

Answer (score 0):

You could set your configuration and then use the -g/--config-dir option when loading.

My startup application looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/transmission-gtk -m
```

You could have your start with the computer booting similar

```
/usr/bin/transmission-gtk -m -g ~/.config/transmission/
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: In my startup application trannsmission is there but has written no description.. Wha am I do to next?

Comment: There is no transmission-gtk in my bin!

Comment: I would like to add that the Transmission is started during boot but it doesn't remember locations and says no data found etc. And then I have to manually set the path again and again every time I boot! Please Help!

Comment: transmission-gtk should be located in the /usr/bin/ and if it's not, you may need to reload the package.  Out of curiosity, how is Transmission auto-starting.  That may be where your issue is stemming from.  If it is starting from a temp session, then it will not have any information where to load or save your config.

Comment: How should it ideally autostart from? How to reload the package? Any risks involved in reloading the package? Plz help! I'm noob! @KentSeaton

Comment: My startup application has been set with this command: transmission-gtk --minimized