# Transmission don't remember session

Tags: transmission

Firstly sorry for my bad English, so I using transmission, but when I close the app and open again, I see nothing, completely nothing, I don't know why, but transmission doesn't remember session and every time when I'm open it, all my active torrent has been removed.

Comment: What version is this `transmission-gtk --version` as a see a bug issue

Comment: It's 2.92 version

Comment: Hava a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/683389/bittorrent-clients-dont-remember-my-save-to-or-move-completed-torrents-to-l

Comment: Please edit your message to include Ubuntu version, and the version of the software that you're using to help others troubleshoot your issues.

Comment: Im using 16.04 and 2.92 transmission